# autostart stuff is not working on lubuntu - mounts and services

Tags: mount, lubuntu, autostart, init.d

I' having problem getting anything non-standard to happen on autostart - I want this PC to function as a media PC, but everytime I lose power or update, I have to manually login and do a bunch of stuff

**FSTAB**

I have an fstab file, wiith two cifs records
when I boot up - nothing is mounted.
if I open a terminal and type

```sh
sudo mount -a
```

everything is mounted fine

**init.d**

I want vncserver to run - I created an /etc/init.d/vncserver.    I ran

```sh
update-rc.d defaults
ls -al /etc/rc?.d | grep vcnserver
```

and got K01vncserver, K01vncserver, S01vncserver

so - as far as I can tell it's enabled.  If I run

```sh
service vncserver start
```

it runs and works perfectly

but it's just not starting on boot.  I put an echo hi >>/var/log/vncserver at the start of the script..  the file isn't appearing.

**the question**

so either I'm doing everything wrong, or something is preventing stuff starting up... or both. I'm probably doing something wrong - but how do I troubleshoot this - I don't see any errors in any logs - in fact if I do a systemctl status vncserver or journalctl | grep vnserver - there's no sign that it ever even tried to start it?

Comment: What release are you using?  We currently have no idea what desktop you are using, nor what software stack you're using.

Comment: I'm running lubuntu / ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (bionic)  


I've actually got it all working now by putting a "service vncserver start" and a "mount -a" in rc.local - still don't understand why it doesn't work without that.

Comment: Please write an answer detailing what you did, and you'll be able to accept it as the answer and gain some rep.  (*I gathered you were using Lubuntu from the tag, an official flavor so on-topic, but that still doesn't tell if it's legacy with LXDE, or modern using LXQt which 18.04.5 does*)